# Share debug.keystore

Tags: android, keystore

Is there any way to share the keystore in a android development team? The goal is to avoid unnecessary uninstall->install cycles. We tried sharing the debug.keystore from .android but it seems that that alone is not working - still getting

> Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.
>
> You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: This
>   will remove the application data!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can copy a debug key from one of your team and provide it to all of the team members.

The debug keystore should be located at `~/.android/debug.keystore`.

A better solution IMO is to use maven and a release-keystore that gets distributed between the developers. You can check the [Immopoly pom file](https://github.com/immopoly/android/blob/master/pom.xml) for seeing a working example config.

Comment: hm - that was not working for us - but good to know that it *should* work - thanks

Comment: If it doesn't work, try deleting the debug.keystore.lock file in the same location