# How to make android debug mode share the same signature across different machines

Tags: android, android-studio-2.0

When debugging android app in android studio with an android device, it will use a default signature. It works fine in one machine however, if I changed another developer machine, android studio will fail to install the app on the device due to the signature mismatch. It is terrible when working with a develop team. How can I let multiple machines share one debug signature?

Comment: Copy the `debug.keystore` from one device to another. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924901/using-the-same-debug-keystore-on-multiple-computers and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365481/share-debug-keystore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sharing android debug certificate across different developer machines in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54178735/sharing-android-debug-certificate-across-different-developer-machines-in-android)