# Sharing android debug certificate across different developer machines in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-app-signing

As Android debug builds get reinstalled when the same phone is connected to different MacBooks, is there any way for all development machines (MacBooks) to share the same debug certificate? It will help to avoid reinstallation on development devices.

Answer (score 12):

Easiest thing to do this would be to check the debug keystore into your project and then reference it in `build.gradle` like so:

```
signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file('../keystore/debug.keystore')
        storePassword "android"
        keyAlias "androiddebugkey"
        keyPassword "android"
    }
    release {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that's possible. Android Studio automatically creates the debug keystore and certificate the first time you run or debug a project in Android Studio.
Simply go to :

- ~/.android/ folder on OS X and Linux
- C:\Documents and Settings\.android\ on Windows XP
- C:\Users\.android\ on Windows Vista and Windows 7, 8, and 10

on one of your development machine and find your debug.keystore file. Copy and paste the file on the other machines at the same location.
Hope it will work!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

To do that, just share the certificate file located at `~.android/debug.keystore` with your teammates.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own keystore for debug builds too. On Mac, this is usually found at `~/.android` folder. To create Keystore, you may do following:

1. Create a `.properties` file with your project name(say, projectname.properties) file and store it somewhere in your project root or elsewhere.
2. Add following entries.

   ```
     keystore=<path>\\filename.keystore
     keystore.password=<password>
   ```
3. Now we need connect `projectname.properties` to our project. Open `gradle.properties` and add an entry.

   ```
    projectname.properties=<path to .properties file>
   ```
4. We can access this properties now in `gradle.build`  file.

   - You can check now if a .properties file is available.

   ```
    if(project.hasProperty("yourprojectname.properties")
     && new File(project.property("yourprojectname.properties")).exists()) {

      Properties propObj = new Properties()
      propObj.load(new FileInputStream(file(project.property("yourprojectname.properties")))
      // now we have 'propObj' object to access keystore.

    }
   ```
5. use this propObj to sign app for debug build.

   ```
    android {
       signingConfigs {
           release {
               //.......
           }
           debug {
               keyAlias 'debug'
               keyPassword propObj['keystore.password']
               storeFile file(propObj['keystore'])
               storePassword propObj['keystore.password']
           }
       }
   ```